# Join multiple tables with condition

Tags: mysql, join

Greetings and thank you for looking at my question.I'm standing as a noob here :) and i have 3 table =>

```
First_Table
First_Table_id  |content
----------
1   |aaa
2   |bbb
3   |ccc
4   |ddd

Second_Table
Second_Table_id  |First_Table_id
----------
1   |1
2   |2
3   |3
4   |4

Third_Table
Third_Table_id  |First_Table_id
----------
1   |1
2   |2
3   |3
```

My problem is, I need to show content from First_Table=>id that filled in Second_Table=>First_Table_id but not filled in Third_Table=>First_Table_id.I've tried to try this =>

```
SELECT * FROM First_Table
LEFT JOIN Second_Table ON Second_Table.First_Table_id = First_Table.id
LEFT JOIN Third_Table ON Third_Table_id WHERE Third_Table.First_Table_id != First_Table.id
```

but that query gives me nothing.Is there another way to solve my problem?Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sub-select:

```
SELECT * FROM First_Table
JOIN Second_Table ON First_Table.id = Second_Table.First_Table_id
WHERE First_Table.id NOT IN (SELECT Third_Table.First_Table_id FROM Third_Table)
```

PS: I used `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` because you said you wanted content from `First_Table` which appears as foreign key in `Second_Table`

Comment: @Vapire that's actually what i'm looking for from last 3 days ago dude :) very appreciate for your help,and thanks so much :)

Comment: @Vapire i must do that,and you remembering me :)